# Conditional probability for marking the exact time at 5 pm

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

After 1 hour, the time elapsed marked by an inaccurate clock is 61
minutes with probability 1/3 and 59 minutes with probability 2/3
If the clock marks the exact time at 7am, what is the probability that it marks the exact time at 5pm?

Hi,

one thing that I am not sure is, is this conditional probability?

P(exact at 5 pm given that exact at 7 am)

Also,

it is not quite unclear that after 1 hour, clock works incorrectly, since there is no way for me to find the probability for being exact at 7 am..

Comment: It is not a "conditional probability" problem. Hint: It must have been $1$ minute fast $5$ times and $1$ minute slow $5$ times. Assume independence.

Comment: In addition, you can use the definition of probability here -- (number of desired cases)/(number of total cases)

Comment: Since it says that after 1 hour, wrong clock marks wrong time,  does that mean that from 7:00am, it marks exact time at 8:00 am and then clock marks the wrong time?

Comment: never mind i got it

Comment: just for final clarification, can I think of it as a binomial case?

Comment: Yes it is binomial. (with the support transformed to $\{-1, 1\}$ for each trial)